# Spotify AndroidSDK - No logout callback

Tags: spotify

When calling Player.logout(), while logged in using Facebook, `PlayerNotificationCallback.onLoggedOut()` is called.

When calling Player.logout(), with a non-premium user that has logged in using Spotify credentials, `PlayerNotificationCallback.onLoggedOut()` is not called.

I don't have a premium account with Spotify credentials to test.

Is this behaviour expected?
I am using the latest Android SDK, `1.0.0-beta12@aar`